# Reclassified image not showing in Google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, mapping, reclassify

What I am trying to do is simply reclassify the spectral indices generated in the google earth engine based on some threshold values. The thresholds are generated in the earth engine platform only. I want that the spectral index values within that threshold range would be classified as 1 and the rest would be 0. I am providing the code and the error I am getting below.

```
var IHR = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/nmsheiari223/assets/Uttarakhand');

// LOADING LANDSAT COLLECTION
//cloud mask
function maskL8sr(col) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = col.select('QA_PIXEL');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return col.updateMask(mask);
}

//DERIVING THE SPECTRAL INDICES (OPTIONAL: TO INCREASE THE ACCURACY)

// Calculation of NDWI
function addndwi(input) {
  var ndwi = input.normalizedDifference(['SR_B2', 'SR_B5']).rename('ndwi');
  return input.addBands(ndwi);
} 

// Calculation of MNDWI
function addmndwi(input) {
  var mndwi = input.normalizedDifference(['SR_B2', 'SR_B6']).rename('mndwi');
  return input.addBands(mndwi);
}

// Calculation of NDVI
function addndvi(input) {
  var ndvi = input.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B4']).rename('ndvi');
  return input.addBands(ndvi);
}

// Calculation of WRI
function addwri(input) {
  var green = input.select('SR_B3');
  var red = input.select('SR_B4');
  var nir = input.select('SR_B5');
  var mir = input.select('SR_B6');
  var wri_n = green.add(red);
  var wri_d = nir.add(mir);
  var wri = wri_n.divide(wri_d).rename('wri');
  return input.addBands(wri);
}

// Calculation of Weighted NDWI (WNDWI) // Weight is considered as 0.5
function addwndwi(input) {
  var green = input.select('SR_B3');
  var nir = input.select('SR_B5');
  var mir = input.select('SR_B6');
  var weight = 0.5;
  var wndwi_n = green.subtract(nir.multiply(weight)).subtract(mir.multiply(0.5));
  var wndwi_d = green.add(nir.multiply(weight)).add(mir.multiply(0.5));
  var wndwi = wndwi_n.divide(wndwi_d).rename('wndwi');
  return input.addBands(wndwi);
}

function addnwi(input) {
  var blue = input.select('SR_B2');
  var nir = input.select('SR_B5');
  var swir1 = input.select('SR_B6');
  var swir2 = input.select('SR_B7');
  var i_sum = nir.add(swir1).add(swir2);
  var nwi_n = blue.subtract(i_sum);
  var nwi_d = blue.add(i_sum);
  var nwi = nwi_n.divide(nwi_d).rename('nwi')
  return input.addBands(nwi);
}
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterDate('2022-04-01', '2022-05-31')
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',30)
    .map(function(image){return image.clip(IHR)})
    .map(maskL8sr)
    .map(addndwi)
    .map(addmndwi)
    .map(addndvi)
    .map(addwri)
    .map(addwndwi)
    .map(addnwi);
    

// Applies scaling factors.
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBand = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBand, null, true);
}

dataset = dataset.map(applyScaleFactors);

var visualization = {
  bands: ['SR_B5', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B3'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
};

Map.centerObject(IHR, 8);

var collection = dataset.median();
Map.addLayer(collection, visualization, 'RGBL (543)');

//Extracting values for NDWI 
var sampled_points_I1 = collection.select('ndwi').sampleRegions({ 
  collection: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  geometries: true
});

var stats_I1 = sampled_points_I1.aggregate_stats('ndwi');
print ('statistical values ndwi', stats_I1);

var samples1 = sampled_points_I1.filter(ee.Filter.gte('ndwi',0));
var stats1 = samples1.aggregate_stats('ndwi');
print ('new statistical values ndwi', stats1);
var mean = samples1.aggregate_mean('ndwi');
print('Sample Mean', mean);
var std = samples1.aggregate_sample_sd('ndwi');
print('Sample Standard Deviation', std);

//Calculating the upper and lower threshold values
var Uth = mean.add(std.multiply(2));
var Lth =  mean.subtract(std.multiply(2));
print('Upper Threshold NDWI', Uth, 'Lower Threshold NDWI', Lth);

var new_Lth = ee.Algorithms.If(Lth.lt(0),0,Lth);
print('Upper Threshold 1', Uth, 'Lower Thresohld 1', new_Lth);

//Extracting values for MNDWI 
var sampled_points_I2 = collection.select('mndwi').sampleRegions({ 
  collection: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  geometries: true
});

var stats_I2 = sampled_points_I2.aggregate_stats('mndwi');
print ('statistical values mndwi', stats_I2);

var samples2 = sampled_points_I2.filter(ee.Filter.gte('mndwi',0));
var stats2 = samples2.aggregate_stats('mndwi');
print ('new statistical values mndwi', stats2);
var mean = samples2.aggregate_mean('mndwi');
print('Sample Mean', mean);
var std = samples2.aggregate_sample_sd('mndwi');
print('Sample Standard Deviation', std);

//Calculating the upper and lower threshold values
var Uth1 = mean.add(std.multiply(2));
var Lth1 =  mean.subtract(std.multiply(2));
print('Upper Threshold MNDWI', Uth1, 'Lower Threshold MNDWI', Lth1);

var new_Lth1 = ee.Algorithms.If(Lth.lt(0),0,Lth);
print('Upper Threshold 2', Uth1, 'Lower Thresohld 2', new_Lth1);

//Extracting values for NDVI 
var sampled_points_I3 = collection.select('ndvi').sampleRegions({ 
  collection: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  geometries: true
});

var stats_I3 = sampled_points_I3.aggregate_stats('ndvi');
print ('statistical values ndvi', stats_I3);

var samples3 = sampled_points_I3.filter(ee.Filter.lt('ndvi',0));
var stats3 = samples3.aggregate_stats('ndvi');
print ('new statistical values ndvi', stats3);
var mean = samples3.aggregate_mean('ndvi');
print('Sample Mean', mean);
var std = samples3.aggregate_sample_sd('ndvi');
print('Sample Standard Deviation', std);

//Calculating the upper and lower threshold values
var Uth = mean.add(std.multiply(2));
var Lth =  mean.subtract(std.multiply(2));
print('Upper Threshold NDVI', Uth, 'Lower Threshold NDVI', Lth);

var new_Uth = ee.Algorithms.If(Uth.gte(0),0,Uth);
print('Upper Threshold 3', new_Uth, 'Lower Thresohld 3', Lth);

//Extracting values for WRI
var sampled_points_I4 = collection.select('wri').sampleRegions({ 
  collection: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  geometries: true
});

var stats_I4 = sampled_points_I4.aggregate_stats('wri');
print ('statistical values wri', stats_I4);

var samples4 = sampled_points_I4.filter(ee.Filter.gte('wri',0));
var stats4 = samples4.aggregate_stats('wri');
print ('new statistical values wri', stats4);
var mean = samples4.aggregate_mean('wri');
print('Sample Mean', mean);
var std = samples4.aggregate_sample_sd('wri');
print('Sample Standard Deviation', std);

//Calculating the upper and lower threshold values
var Uth = mean.add(std.multiply(2));
var Lth =  mean.subtract(std.multiply(2));
print('Upper Threshold WRI', Uth, 'Lower Threshold WRI', Lth);

var new_Lth = ee.Algorithms.If(Lth.lt(0),0,Lth);
print('Upper Threshold 4', Uth, 'Lower Thresohld 4', new_Lth);

//Extracting values for WNDWI 
var sampled_points_I5 = collection.select('wndwi').sampleRegions({ 
  collection: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  geometries: true
});

var stats_I5 = sampled_points_I5.aggregate_stats('wndwi');
print ('statistical values wndwi', stats_I5);

var samples5 = sampled_points_I5.filter(ee.Filter.gte('wndwi',0));
var stats5 = samples5.aggregate_stats('wndwi');
print ('new statistical values wndwi', stats5);
var mean = samples5.aggregate_mean('wndwi');
print('Sample Mean', mean);
var std = samples5.aggregate_sample_sd('wndwi');
print('Sample Standard Deviation', std);

//Calculating the upper and lower threshold values
var Uth = mean.add(std.multiply(2));
var Lth =  mean.subtract(std.multiply(2));
print('Upper Threshold WNDWI', Uth, 'Lower Threshold WNDWI', Lth);

var new_Lth = ee.Algorithms.If(Lth.lt(0),0,Lth);
print('Upper Threshold 5', Uth, 'Lower Thresohld 5', new_Lth);

//Extracting values for NWI 
var sampled_points_I6 = collection.select('nwi').sampleRegions({ 
  collection: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  geometries: true
});

var stats_I6 = sampled_points_I6.aggregate_stats('nwi');
print ('statistical values nwi', stats_I6);

var samples6 = sampled_points_I6.filter(ee.Filter.gte('nwi',0));
var stats6 = samples6.aggregate_stats('nwi');
print ('new statistical values nwi', stats6);
var mean = sampled_points_I6.aggregate_mean('nwi');
print('Sample Mean', mean);
var std = sampled_points_I6.aggregate_sample_sd('nwi');
print('Sample Standard Deviation', std);

//Calculating the upper and lower threshold values
var Uth = mean.add(std.multiply(2));
var Lth =  mean.subtract(std.multiply(2));
print('Upper Threshold NWI', Uth, 'Lower Threshold NWI', Lth);

var new_Lth = ee.Algorithms.If(Lth.lt(0),0,Lth);
print('Upper Threshold 6', Uth, 'Lower Thresohld 6', new_Lth);

// Reclassify the waterbodies

var ndwi = collection.select('ndwi');
var ndwi_rec = ee.Image(ndwi)
          .where(ndwi.gt(new_Lth1).and(ndwi.lte(Uth1)), 1)
          .where(ndwi.gt(-1).and(ndwi.lte(new_Lth)),0);


Map.addLayer(ndwi_rec, {},'ndwi_water');
```

The code is running error free till the last reclassification. But whenever I am applying the Map.addLayer, I'm getting the below error.

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`new_Lth1` is `computedObject` kind, not number kind. So if you want to use it in the comparison convert it:

```
var ndwi_rec = ndwi
          .where(ndwi.gt(ee.Number(new_Lth1)).and(ndwi.lte(Uth1)), 1)
          .where(ndwi.gt(-1).and(ndwi.lte(ee.Number(new_Lth))),0);
```

Using a custom geometry for testing it:

[image]